# converting column into single row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to wrangle my dataset converting a column into a single row.

Original dataset:

[image]

What I am getting is

[image]

What I want to have:

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- test %>%
  group_by(cusip, year, typecode, ticker, stkname, indcode) %>%
  summarise(mean_shares=mean(shares), mean_prc=mean(prc))

df_2 <- df%>%
  spread(typecode, mean_shares, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Image as part of question doesn't help.  Could you please add output of `dput(test)` as part of question. If your data is very big then you can simply add output of `dput(head(test,20))`

Comment: I suspect the problem stems from your missing values being listed as zeroes in the input data.frame. Try doing the same thing with "NA" instead of "0".

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are getting a separate row for each value of `mean_prc` because it differs for each `typecode`. It's unclear what should be filling the cell values in the output you wish to have, as each row already has a `mean_shares` column.

To illustrate the point:

```
#create reproducible dataframe
test <- data.frame(expand.grid(cusip = c(36020, 78549, 22102, 87354), 
                               year = 2000:2003, typecode = 1:5, 
                               ticker = c("ABC", "BDF", "ASFK", "JERG")),
                   shares = rnorm(320, 100, 60),
                   prc = rnorm(320, 60, 5))

df <- test %>%
  group_by(cusip, year, typecode, ticker) %>%
  summarise(mean_shares=mean(shares), mean_prc=mean(prc)) %>%
  spread(typecode, mean_shares, fill = 0)
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
# Groups:   cusip, year [1]
  cusip  year ticker mean_prc   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <dbl> <int> <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 22102  2000 ABC        59.3   0      0   136.    0    0  
2 22102  2000 ABC        60.1   0      0     0     0   27.4
3 22102  2000 ABC        60.6  53.8    0     0     0    0  
4 22102  2000 ABC        61.7   0      0     0   268.   0  
5 22102  2000 ABC        65.5   0    168.    0     0    0  
6 22102  2000 BDF        54.7   0      0   141.    0    0
```

Now if we drop `mean_prc`, it will fill in all the values per row:

```
df_2 <-test %>%
  group_by(cusip, year, typecode, ticker) %>%
  summarise(mean_shares=mean(shares), mean_prc=mean(prc)) %>%
  #drop mean_prc
  select(-mean_prc) %>%
  spread(typecode, mean_shares, fill = 0)

head(df_2)

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   cusip, year [2]
  cusip  year ticker   `1`    `2`    `3`    `4`      `5`
  <dbl> <int> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 22102  2000 ABC     53.8  168.  136.    268.    27.4  
2 22102  2000 BDF     57.6   73.9 141.     70.4   52.3  
3 22102  2000 ASFK   212.   113.    4.77  -13.7   -0.240
4 22102  2000 JERG    36.7   42.9  63.7   165.   215.   
5 22102  2001 ABC     19.6   13.4  10.5   -23.8   97.5  
6 22102  2001 BDF    110.   -11.6 127.     62.4  110.
```

In short you need to make sure that you aren't trying to spread your data while having another variable that is unique to each level of the factor over which you are trying to spread.